# bootstrap - button group - button being cut off on left hand side

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

**Problem:** 
A button group I've created using bootstrap css appears cut off on the left, as you can see below.

[image]

**Code:**

I have the following HTML logic:

```
<div class="span5">
        <div class="row show-grid"> 
        <div class="btn-group>
            <button class="btn dropdown-toggle hidden-desktop visible-phone btn-warning" data-toggle="dropdown">show info&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><div id="address"><?php echo anchor("mycontroller/method1/".$objectid,'addresses'); ?></div></li>
              <li><div id="logs"><?php echo anchor("mycontroller/method2/",'logs'); ?></div></li>
              <li><div id="status"><?php echo anchor("mycontroller/method3/",'status'); ?></div></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <br/>
            <div class="span2"><?php echo anchor("mycontroller/method4/","Back to List")?></div>
  </div><!-- end class row show-grid-->     
  <br/> 
</div>
```

**What I've Tried So Far:**

I've been using Firefox's Inspect tool to try to find the differences between the top button and the bottom,  but I don't know what property I should be looking for. I've tried modifying properties like:

```
padding-left
padding-right
margin-left 
margin-right
```

I've also tried to reduce the number of classes applied to the button so that I only had:

```
<button class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
```

But that didn't resolve the problem. Can someone point me in the right direction?  Perhaps by naming the types of properties I should be tracking down?  It's probably a CSS specificity problem... because I haven't modified any of the bootstrap stuff.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post your css code, or live example of it. That could help defining a problem in minutes

Comment: you have my answer below why, and the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using a button group for buttons that aren't grouped together?  The reason it's "cut off" is because button groups are supposed to be merged together.

Regardless, it's displayed like that because the inner borders of the buttons don't have rounded edges.  You can fix it by manually applying the border radius:

```
border-top-left-radius: 4px; border-bottom-left-radius: 4px
```

Comment: Thanks.  That must of have old code. I've removed button group and that resolved the issue! No extra code required to set radius values

Comment: actually, i spoke too soon. when you remove the button group <div> it fixes the look of the "show info" button i have, but it breaks the functionality.  so you can't click on it and have it display the drop down items

Comment: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns - the first example shows that you need a button group

Comment: "border-top-left-radius: 4px; border-bottom-left-radius: 4px" works.  although I still don't know why it's behaving this way.

Comment: -1 for both the question and the solution. The marked answer doesn't have to do anything with the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Give this CSS

```
.btn{
display:block;
padding:XXpx;
margin:XXpx;
height:XXpx;
width:XXpx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OMG, 
the answer is:

to change from:

```
<div class="btn-group>
```

to:

```
<div class="btn-group">
```

You forgot the `"`

You can see the live fix here: http://jsfiddle.net/kCsEs/

Comment: Aleks, that didn't resolve the problem... the button is still cut off

Comment: if it doesn't help, then it is all a bit guessing. Could you copy-paste your css code, or even better create live example on http://jsbin.com/ or any other. that would help a lot

Answer (score 0):

this is a hack fix but on the containing div that is wrapped around the button - you may simply have

overflow:hidden

Inspect in chrome with firebug and go up and you will most likely see this.. Bootstrap hides data that overflows the columns.

Comment: I'm in Inspect and I've chosen the "computed" tab so I can see all properties / attributes of the div... overflow is not set.  Neither is overflow-x and overflow-y

Answer (score 0):

**Following solved my problem**

```
.btn {
     width:auto !important;
}
```